# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource beep.wav can not be loaded' iOS Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm making a game for iPad with Sprite Kit (Objective-C).

I often use following code (for example):

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"beep.wav" waitForCompletion:YES]];
```

All goes well, until after a while my app crashes and i suddenly got following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource beep.wav can not be loaded'
```

I have no idea why, because the sound could be loaded en played correctly before the error.

The same error can also occur with other sounds, but always after some time.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try using the Project navigator pane, right click on beep.wav the Show in Finder. Does this locate the file in Finder?

Comment: Yes, it can be found.

Comment: audio actions really are not production ready (no control over audio whatsoever, no error reporting), better to use avaudioplayer or a proper audio engine like objectal

Comment: btw, why is it throwing an exception, if we are supposed to not use them and cannot either catch them in swift? seems like we must build an objective c wrapper around the playSoundFile action just to catch this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to preload the sounds and keep a reference to the action in your controller.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) SKAction *playMySound;`

and initialise it:

`self.playMySound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"beep.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];`

and just use it:

`[self runAction:playMySound]`

You will keep a reference to the action, and will avoid reloading the file each time you want the sound to play.